# Finding a serial killer

Tags: knowledge, cipher, geography, steganography

Recently, in the United States, there have been multiple murders all over the country. Because of how similar these murders are, it is believed that a single individual is responsible. There have been no leads in catching this individual; however, one day, the FBI receives a photo with a sticky note that says:

> this is who and where i am

Can you find out what this means?

Here is the photo:

[image: Check Spoiler]

If the photo is not visible for you:

> The photo not being on imgur is important to the puzzle. Sorry for the trouble.
>  https://junewi.000webhostapp.com/testing/md5.jpg

HINT:

> Check the end of the inside of the photo

Comment: I don't believe alper has the reputation required to make a comment. Is there any way that you could also provide the imgur link as well? Embedded pictures sometimes are not entirely visible when posted, unfortunately.

Comment: I see! I'm going to post it as a hint though

Comment: jwi, I think it would be better supported as a i.stack.imgur image on this website if at all possible, rather than on a personal website! It might make it more viewable for users (including myself).

Comment: rot13(fbeel! gurer'f n ernfba jul vg'f ba zl fvgr naq abg vzthe. unf gb qb jvgu gur chmmyr!!!)

Comment: I can't see the image either. Is this intentional? If not, you may want to consider finding a way to upload to i.stack.imgur -- without this, your puzzle may break in the future. Puzzles here should generally be completely self-contained.

Comment: sorry about that! check the spoiler tag!

Comment: The image is now a dead link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The map is clearly

> [Jacksonville, Florida](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacksonville,_Florida)

Looking at the picture,

> The file name is md5.jpg, which shows we will need to use MD5 decryption.

Based on the hint,

> A MD5 encrypted hex string can be found
> `39917473a0ad7771f532e123c919be05`

Decrypting,

> Gives `I am apathy, i am adryan ghaya`

Meaning

> The killer is Adryan Ghaya, and he is in Jacksonville, Florida

Answer (score 4):

Here are some observations in case it helps anyone.

> The first thing I noticed is that the filename is md5.jpg which is probably why the OP doesn't want to upload to imgur. So following this hint, if we take the MD5 of the image we get `9366896BC04D70A502BF32B07BFD6573`. This is where I am stuck because I don't see anything special about the md5.

Edit based off hint:

> The hint suggests checking "the end of the inside of the photo". Opening the image with a text editor we find `39917473a0ad7771f532e123c919be05`. This is a 128-bit hex string which indicates an MD5 hash. This is it for now. I will try digging deeper later when I have more time.

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> The Golden King of El Dorado?

Reasoning

> The map seems similar to the state Mississippi, but the border on the west does not seem to fit. If I draw the borders myself, the black dot on the left of the map is no longer in the state Mississippi, but in Arkansas or Louisiana. It is pretty much over the city *El Dorado*. In the absence of any further clue to *who* you are (At least I didn't find them), I assume you are the Golden King of El Dorado.
> While drawing borders on the image I realized that the original state was too far off to be mississippi and therefore that my answer is probably incorrect.
>  [image: My Image]

Comment: Sorry, not quite!!

Answer (score 1):

> i am apathy, i am adryan ghaya

Based on the hint

> When I checked the source code of the picture I found this hash at the end: 39917473a0ad7771f532e123c919be05

Based on Bennett's observation

> Putting the hash into an MD5 decrypter led to the answer above.

Comment: So close! Casey got the full answer.